# Identify sequences in alphanumeric strings in R

Tags: r, dataframe, sequence, information-extraction, identify

I am attempting to create a flag for when transaction IDs are sequential.  For reasons that I will not get into here, these can be a red flag.  The problem that I am having is that the IDs are not standardized.  Some can be numeric only and others are alphanumeric.  I want to identify cases where a vendor's transactions are sequential for X number (how many in a row TBD) of transactions.  The data will be grouped by vendor and I'd like to extract all rows and columns for instances where a sequence is present.  A much simplified example below:

```
df <- read.table(text=
"Vendor        'Transaction ID'
 ACME               1
 ACME               2
 ACME               3
 JDOE               A1
 JDOE               A6
 JDOE               A10
 XYZ                B12
 XYZ                B13
 XYZ                B14", header=TRUE)
```

In this instance I would want to extract the Vendor and Transaction ID for all ACME and all XYZ rows since they are in a sequence.  I've done some research but not found an approach that seems to fit what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option is to convert the `Transaction_ID` to a number using `parse_number`, then you can create a grouping column for consecutive values within each group. Then, you can `filter` depending on how many consecutive numbers you want to have. Here, I use greater than 1, but you can update the `filter` statement depending on your desired criteria. Then, I ungroup and remove the extra columns - `Transaction_ID2` and `grp`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(readr)

df %>%
  mutate(Transaction_ID2 = parse_number(Transaction_ID)) %>%
  group_by(Vendor, grp = cumsum(c(1, diff(Transaction_ID2) != 1))) %>%
  filter(n() > 1) %>% 
  ungroup %>% 
  select(-c(Transaction_ID2, grp))
```

**Output**

```
  Vendor Transaction_ID
  <chr>  <chr>         
1 ACME   1             
2 ACME   2             
3 ACME   3             
4 XYZ    B12           
5 XYZ    B13           
6 XYZ    B14
```

Answer (score 1):

My earlier version used the stringr and as.numeric, but I really like the `parse_number()` function from Andrew's answer, so I am ruthlessly stealing it ^_^

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  filter(Transaction.ID %>% 
          parse_number() %>%
          diff() %>%
          {all(. == 1)}, .by = Vendor)
```

Answer (score 1):

Packages are more elegant, but for good measure, a base R approach would be to use `tapply` to create a boolean after looking for sequential numbers by groups, then [indexing]:

```
xx <- tapply(df$Transaction.ID, df$Vendor, function(x) 
  length(rle(diff(as.numeric(gsub("[A-Za-z]", '\\1', x))))$lengths) == 1)

# ACME  JDOE   XYZ 
# TRUE FALSE  TRUE 

df[df$Vendor %in% names(xx[xx]),]

#  Vendor Transaction.ID
#1   ACME              1
#2   ACME              2
#3   ACME              3
#7    XYZ            B12
#8    XYZ            B13
#9    XYZ            B14
```